# Four logical conclusions regarding a 3x3 matrix representing a differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\mathbf{x'}=\mathbf{Ax}$ be a system of linear differential equations with constant coefficients, where $\mathbf{A}$ is a 3x3 matrix that has exactly two different real eigenvalues. Which of the following statements is/are correct?

1. The system has no basic system of solutions, all the elements of which are of the form $e^{λt}\mathbf{v}$, where λ is a real number and $\mathbf v$ is a vector of real numbers.
2. The system has a basic system of solutions, all the elements of which are of the form $e^{λt}\mathbf{v}$, where λ is a real number and $\mathbf v$ is a vector of real numbers.
3. The system has a solution that is not of the form $e^{λt}\mathbf{v}$, where λ is a real number and $\mathbf v$ is a vector of real numbers.
4. The system has a solution, all three elements of which approach $\infty$ or $-\infty$ when $t\to\infty$, or it has a solution all three elements of which approach $\infty$ or $-\infty$ when $t\to-\infty$.

1 and 3 seem wrong to me on a logical level, 2 on the face of it seems right, whereas I am utterly confused regarding 4. Can anybody help out? Many thanks!

Comment: Things to consider: What must the third eigenvalue be? Can you conclude that $\mathbf A$ is diagonalizable? In either case, what must the possible basic solutions look like?

Comment: @amd So I concluded that there is one eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 2, and one with algebraic multiplicity 1. In order to analyze whether $A$ is diagonalizable, I would need to know the geometric multiplicity, right? I seem unable to find that based on what is given...

Comment: Since you can’t tell whether or not the matrix is diagonalizable, you have two cases to consider.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, but that leaves me more or less in the same state: I still do not know how to advance :s

Comment: Isolate the problematic part, then: What are the possible forms of the general solution when $\mathbf A$ is $2\times2$ and has a repeated (real) eigenvalue?

Comment: This indeed initially led me to reject 1. and 3. and accept 2. and 4. However, there is  only one correct answer, so there is a mistake in my reasoning somewhere...

Comment: If you can’t conclude that the matrix is diagonalizable, then how can you conclude that 2. is true?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you’re close to getting the answer on your own. As you say, there is a repeated real eigenvalue, but it’s not possible to tell whether or not the matrix is diagonalizable. This means that the general solution will have one of two forms: either $e^{\lambda_1t}\mathbf v_1+e^{\lambda_1t}\mathbf v_2+e^{\lambda_2t}\mathbf v_3$ or $e^{\lambda_1t}\mathbf v_1+te^{\lambda_1t}\mathbf v_2+e^{\lambda_2t}\mathbf v_3$. Draw conclusions about the four statements from that.